# Easiest way to make Swing-JTabbedPane-Tabs fill the whole width of their container

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I'm having a JTabbedPane (with horizontal tabs on the top) in a JPanel, and I want the tabs of this JTabbedPane to fit the whole width of the JPanel, so that if there's only one tab, the tab would fill the whole width; when there are two tabs, each tab would fill excactly the half, and so on.

Using a custom JComponent as a the title of the tabs and setting the PreferredSize there isn't a solution since it seems that JTabbedPanel puts some sort of border around the title-components.

Is there any easier solution than extending and/or rewriting part/all of JTabbedPane?

(Maybe I should add that when I'm talking about tabs, I refer to these navigational components you can click on to switch the component shown, and not the components themselves.)

Comment: it depends how far you're willing to go.  Sometimes for things seemingly very simple it's actually easier to rewrite the entire component yourself (I didn't write it was easy, I just said it was often easier than trying to fix Swing).  For example, imagine you want OS-native table display, where the scrollbar takes all the height of the JTable, **including the JTable headers**... Well, good luck. This is a Swing-app dead giveaway. It looks fugly. And there's not much to do about it besides basically rewriting a nicer JTable. Don't know anything about your specific case that said.

Comment: Yes, rewriting was basically what I did to solve the problem (using CardLayout). But it now actually doesn't look very professional, so I was wondering whether there is some straightforward way via JTabbedPane.

Comment: what's your layoutManager of JPanel ? [BorderLayout suitable for this work. ]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Test this code :

```
public class Tabs extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public Tabs() {
        initComponents();
    }


       private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jTabbedPane1 = new javax.swing.JTabbedPane();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());

        jPanel2.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());


        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab1", jPanel2);


        jPanel3.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());


        jTabbedPane1.addTab("tab2", jPanel3);

        jPanel1.add(jTabbedPane1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(jPanel1);

        pack();
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tabs().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of using BorderLayout inside the titlecomponents, but it works.

Comment: Rather than post two answers, why not simply edit your previous answer?

Comment: sorry.i remember this advice for next answer.

Comment: instead of waiting till the next time you answer, you can fix this now.  Delete one answer and put the two together.

Comment: @kohlehydrat This answer is not correct! I tested it and the tabs don't fill frame width. Why is this answer marked as correct ?!!

Comment: @SeyedMohammad I'd say this is correct. Setting the panel's layout to BorderLayout worked fine for me. Perhaps your problem is something entirely different?

Comment: @SimonAndreForsberg If you are saying that the above code is working, then I have to disagree. Because I simply copied the code and run it and the tab-headers don't fill the panel's width. If you're talking about another code, then I'd be happy to have a look at it (you can send the code using: http://paste.ubuntu.com)